# Sum of dirac measure is a measure

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $x=(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb R$. For $A \subset \mathbb R$, let $\mu_x (A) = \sum \delta_{x_n} (A)$, where $\delta_x$ is the dirac-measure.

Why is $\mu_x$ a measure on $(\mathbb R, P( \mathbb R))$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly $\mu_x(\emptyset)=0$ and the measure is non-negative. Moreover, the $\sigma$-additivity holds basically because, whenever $\{A_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a family of pairwise disjoint subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there is at most one $i \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n \in A_i$. Then $\sum\mu_x(A_i)$ and $\mu_x(\cup A_i)$ are always the same element of $\{0,1,2,...,\infty\}$.

Answer (score 3):

A more general fact: if $\mu_n$ is a sequence of measures and $\mu(A)=\sum_n \mu_n(A)$ then $\mu$ is a measure. Countable additivity of $\mu$ follows from the following elementary lemma:

if $a_{nm} \geq 0$ for all $n,m$ then $\sum_n \sum_m a_{nm}=\sum_m \sum_n a_{nm}$. Apply this with $a_{nm}=\mu_n(A_m)$ where $(A_m)$ is a given disjoint sequence in the sigma field.